# Javascript integer to binary string round trip loses bits

Tags: javascript, binary

I'm trying to convert a binary string to an integer and back again in javascript (Mostly so I can move my binary arrays across a network and more efficiently). Only I'm having a problem. It appears that while converting a 64-bit array back and forth, I lose some of the bits.

My conversion functions looks like this:

```
Utils = {
  dec2bin: function(dec, size) {
    return (dec).toString(2);
  },
  bin2dec: function(str) {
    return parseInt(str, 2);
  }
}
```

This seems to work on a small scale...

```
Utils.bin2dec('101');
// 5
Utils.dec2bin(5);
// '101'
```

However, when I start to look at a longer integer, the last few positive bits seem to vanish:

```
var start = '1000000101000010001001000001100000011000001001000100001010000001';
var integer = Utils.bin2dec(start);
var end = Utils.dec2bin(integer);
console.log(start)
console.log(end)
```

The above code results in:

```
1000000101000010001001000001100000011000001001000100001010000001
1000000101000010001001000001100000011000001001000100000000000000
```

Notice towards the end all of my 1's are 0's.

If I remove the fist few positive bits, the end seems to maintain its integrity...

```
0000000000000010001001000001100000011000001001000100001010000001
              10001001000001100000011000001001000100001010000001
```

(I can easily pad out the first few 0's later)

So the question is this. Can I store 64 bits in a single integer in Javascript? How?

Alternatively, how can I make this round trip with multiple integers?

Comment: Javascript doesn't have an integer datatype. A Javascript number is 64-bit floating point.

Comment: @user2357112 So why can't I store, then retrieve 64 binary digits?

Comment: Because you can't stuff 64 bits of precision into a 64-bit floating-point number. It needs room for the sign and exponent.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks, I understand the problem a little better now.